# How do I get historical bar data for SPX using Interactive Broker's Native Python API?

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I am just trying to get historical bar data for SPX. Is there a method to "figure out" the appropriate contract because I cannot seem to do it.

```
from ibapi.client import *
from ibapi.wrapper import *


class TestApp(EClient, EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        
    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
        mycontract = Contract()
        mycontract.symbol = 'SPX'
        mycontract.secType = 'IND'
        mycontract.exchange = 'CBOE'
        mycontract.currency = 'USD'
        
        #self.reqMarketDataType(4)
        self.reqHistoricalData(orderId, mycontract, "20230126-23:59:59", "1 D", "1 hour", "TRADES", 0, 1, 0, [])
        #self.reqMktData(orderId, mycontract, "", 0, 0, [])
        
    #def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
    #   print(f"tickPrice reqId: {reqId}, ticktype: {TickTypeEnum.to_str(tickType)}, price: {price}, attrib: {attrib}")
        
    #def tickSize(self, reqId, tickType, size):
    #    print(f"tickSize reqId: {reqId}, ticktype: {TickTypeEnum.to_str(tickType)}, size: {size}")
    
    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        print(f"Historical Data: {bar}")
        
    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId, start, end):
        print(f"End of Historical Data")
        print(f"start: {start}, end: {end}")


app = TestApp()
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 1000)
app.run()
```

This is the closest I've managed to come - says I don't have market data subscription. I guess I don't. Can someone with a market data subscription confirm that this works?

Also, is there a good guide on getting started with Interactive Brokers Native Python API? I find creating apps that inherit from both EClient and EWrapper really unintuitive. Perhaps that's a topic for another thread.

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](https://groups.io/g/twsapi/topic/how_to_get_spx_index_data/4047244?p=).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using EUR.USD contract to test for your data request since that contract does not require market data subscription.

[image: EUR/USD contract]

I think EClient and EWrapper classes from the native Interactive Brokers (IB) python API can be a bit tricky to comprehend, especially since it requires some solid understandings of class inheritance, asynchronous process, decorator design pattern, etc.  If you simply just want to do research using data from IB, then maybe try ib-insync package, so you won't have to override much of the code from EWrapper to handle data received from EClient.

But if you really want to use ibapi, then here's the answer to your question:

You first need to write your own class that inherits from both EClient and EWrapper classes. To simplify this a bit more, think of EClient as requests you want to send to IB, and EWrapper as messages you will receive from requests by EClient.  So to distinguish every request, you need a request ID, i.e. reqId.  Here's the code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import threading, time

from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.client import BarData
from ibapi.utils import iswrapper


class IB(EClient, EWrapper):

    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.data = []

    @iswrapper
    def error(self, reqId, code, msg):
        '''Logging Error'''
        print(f"Error {reqId}, code: {code}, message: {msg}")

    @iswrapper
    def historicalData(self, reqId: int, bar: BarData) -> None:
        self.data.append([bar.date, bar.open, bar.high, bar.low, bar.close, bar.volume])

    @iswrapper
    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId: int, start: str, end: str):
        start_time = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
        end_time = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
        super().historicalDataEnd(reqId, start, end)
        print("Historical data request with request ID: ", reqId, " for period between ",
              start_time, " and ", end_time, " is complete.")


def create_contract() -> Contract:
    ticker = Contract()
    ticker = Contract()
    ticker.symbol = 'SPY'
    ticker.secType = 'STK'
    ticker.exchange = 'SMART'
    ticker.currency = 'USD'
    return ticker


def run_loop(app):
    app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = IB()
    app.connect(host='localhost', port=7496, clientId=1)
    time.sleep(2)
    api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, args=(app,))
    api_thread.start()

    ticker = create_contract()
    
    query_time = datetime(2023, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc).strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
    app.reqHistoricalData(reqId=2,
                          contract=ticker,
                          endDateTime=query_time,
                          durationStr='2 W',
                          barSizeSetting='1 day',
                          whatToShow='TRADES',
                          useRTH=1,
                          formatDate=2,
                          keepUpToDate=False,
                          chartOptions=[])
    time.sleep(2)
    for bar in app.data:
        print(bar)
    app.disconnect()
```

The `historicalData` and `historicalDataEnd` are methods that belong to EWrapper class. So when I rewrote these, I put @iswrapper as a mental note to myself that these methods were overriden.  If you pay close attention to methods under @iswrapper and the output below, I had ways to handle callbacks from requests that I sent out, i.e. error() to handle app.connect(), historicalData() to handle data received and to append them to self.data, and historicalDataEnd() to let us know, the request was complete. That said, for every request you send out using EClient, you need a way to handle messages received in EWrapper.  At the end, I basically just print out data from TestApp.  I hope this will help you get started!

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. Just need to subscribe to the correct data subscription as mentioned in the forum.

https://ndcdyn.interactivebrokers.com/forum/#/post/65423

For SPX: CBOE Streaming Market Indexes

For SPX Options: OPRA (US Options Exchanges)